Is besamim used for Motzai Shabbat when there is an important event
According to Halacha, besamim is not used  for havdalah when  Motzai Shabbat is Yom tov. My question is, if there is a wedding, bar mitzvah, Brit milah, etc. being held  the day after Shabbat, does similar reasoning apply and is besamim not used?

@יהושעק ...or it's a proof your reason is incorrect.

The reason we do not use besamim is because the simcha of entering Yom Tov is enough that we do not become depressed that Shabbos is leaving. Alternatively, the good food on Yom Tov is what helps us get over the loss of Shabbos.
Either way, there is no intrinsic simcha for the general public because of a private event, so the initial decree of Chazal to require besamim is still intact. Therefore, besamim should be used.

Please remember to quote sources in your answers
